# Is there a way to specify a environment variable and define a value for each environment in gitlab UI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to create an environment variable like `DB_URL` and them define a different value for dev, test and production. I couldn't find a way to do it using gitlab UI.

EDIT: I know how to create a variable and how to define an environment for it. The point is that I need the same variable (same name) with a different value for each environment. I can define only one pair (environment, value) per variable. I would like to define many.

PS: I'm using gitlab coummunity edition.

Comment: I asked for a specific way of achieving a task using gitlab ui.

Comment: I'm using gitlab to deploy my application, so I'm using it to define the environment variables used in my code.

Comment: Are you saying that environment variables which you can create on gitlab are only for CI purposes? It doesn't look like that from their documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/